# Coq - trivial induction on lists doesn't accept assumtion

Tags: coq, induction

In my current proof, I end up requiring the following result for the `else` situation of a case disjunction.

```
1 subgoal (ID 28899)
  
  l : list (Concrete.cvalue sem)
  ============================
  match l with
  | [] | _ => True
  end
```

I therefore intend to proceed with a trivial induction on my list, by applying `induction l. apply I.`, and I end up with

```
1 subgoal (ID 28909)
  
  a : Concrete.cvalue sem
  l : list (Concrete.cvalue sem)
  IHl : match l with
        | [] | _ => True
        end
  ============================
  match l with
  | [] | _ => True
  end
```

However, once here, he doesn't accept `assumption` nor `exact IHl`, saying that

```
Error:
In environment
a : Concrete.cvalue sem
l : list (Concrete.cvalue sem)
IHl : match l with
      | [] | _ => True
      end
The term "IHl" has type "match l with
                         | [] | _ => True
                         end" while it is expected to have type
 "match l with
  | [] | _ => True
  end".
```

Do you have any idea of what may be in cause, and how to solve it?

Comment: It's definitely strange to see an error message of the form "has type X while it is expected to be X", with X being exactly the same in the two places. I'd file a bug report on Coq using a minimal reproducible example file, telling them that Coq should be more specific or precise in its error messages.